# Consulta SQL sin éxito frente a una cadena JSON en formato unicode

Tags: mysql, json

En la tabla de una base de datos MySQL almaceno el siguiente campo con datos concretos de un usuario convirtiendo los acentos a unicode (esto no es modificable ya que los datos deben ir así obligatoriamente para mi caso), por ejemplo, para el usuario Lázaro Torres el campo `userdata` (tipo text) quedaría tal que así:

```
{"nombre":"L\u00e1zaro","apellidos":"Torres"}
```

El problema viene al hacer un `LIKE` para obtener la fila de Lázaro. La siguiente consulta me devuelve 0 filas:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE userdata LIKE "%L\u00e1zaro%";
```

¿Qué estoy pasando por alto?

Comment: Creo que esto te puede servir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287145/mysql-querying-for-unicode-entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tú no estás guardando esa cadena en unicode, la estás guardando en *ASCII*, dado que todos esos carácteres son *ASCII*.

Lo que realmente estás haciendo es sustituir carácteres no *ASCII* por una *unicode escape sequence* (es decir, especificar el code point del carácter deseado, en vez de escribir el carácter directamente).

Dado que *MySQL* no tiene soporte para *unicode escape sequences*, tu `\u00e1` no tiene ningún significado especial, y se transforma, en la base de datos, simplemente como:

```
 {"nombre":"Lu00e1zaro","apellidos":"Torres"}
```

ya que *MySQL* ha visto una barra (`\`), ha visto que no se está utilizando para escapar nada (`\u` no tiene ningún significado especial para *MySQL*, al contrario que en otros lenguajes), y sencillamente se ignora la barra.

Por tanto, lo que tendrías que hacer para insertar es:

```
 {"nombre":"L\\u00e1zaro","apellidos":"Torres"}
```

Para asegurarte de que la barra se guarda. Y luego para buscar, tienes que utilizar cuatro barras (porque en `like`s la cadena se parsea dos veces, una por el cliente *MySQL*, para ver qué carácteres mandar al servidor, y otra por el propio *pattern matcher*):

```
 select * from usuarios where userdata like "%L\\\\u00e1zaro%";
```

Y se mostrarán los resultados deseados.

Si fuese un `where ... =` solo tendrías que escapar una vez:

```
select * from usuario where userdata = "L\\ue1zaro";
```

Más información sobre el cuádruple escapado, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926386/how-to-search-for-slash-in-mysql-and-why-escaping-not-required-for-wher).

Comment: Me ha sido de gran ayuda, imaginaba que sería algo relacionado con el carácter de escape pero desconocía el doble parseado en una sentencia con LIKE. Gracias.